# history.back is breaking bind('scroll')

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, browser-history

On the document ready of my page I bind the scroll event like this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() 
{
    alert('scroll');
});
```

Now this is working perfectly. But when I navigate to a page and then navigate back using history.back the code is not executed anymore. While other binds like 'click' are still working.

How can I solve this? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the "pageshow" and "pagehide" event and recalling the javascript